# SQL server zoom to extent for geography

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

I am working with spatial objects in SQL server 2016/2019.

If I select a geometry, SQL server gives me a nice spatial view that shows the geometry nice and big in the screen.

But if I do the same with a geography object I get a zoomed out world wide view and I cannot hardly see the object nor have any good way to find it.

is there a solutiion?